# __declspec(property()) and class declarator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, properties, declspec

So I've been trying to implement the same type of get and set like in C#. But something generated some doubts about how the variables are declared under the hood in c++. Here's the code:

```
class foo {
    foo Getter() {
        return *this;
    }
    foo f; //this isn't allowed
    __declspec(property(get = Getter)) foo f2; // but this IS
};
```

What's really happening here?

Comment: `__declspec(property)` is a compiler-specific extension and not standard C++. Please add a tag for your compiler (I guess `visual-c++`). C++ does not have properties.

Comment: The `foo f;` declaration is invalid, because `foo` is not a complete type at this point. You cannot have a type be member of itself (but you can have a pointer or reference to the type itself as member).

Comment: I get your point. But what specifically  does `__declspec(property())` do to allow a non complete type to be declared here?

Comment: Yes, it is visual-c++ (forgot to add the tag, adding now)

Comment: `f2` is just syntactic sugar over `Getter()`, so there's no actual `Foo` member. Because of that, the incomplete declaration is enough to make it valid.

Comment: I was surprised to learn this works in clang too with a flag: https://godbolt.org/z/FgkXsn